# How to add timestamp to Minutes in php

Tags: php

```
$date = 10/24/14
$time = 10:10
$mtc = 180 minutes
```

After using strtotime function i am getting timestamp,

```
echo strtotime('10/24/14 10:10');
timestamp is 1414138200
```

How can i add timestamp to 180 minutes. Can any one please help me.

Comment: Can u clarify your question? What you really need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understand your question well, you just can add the seconds to the current timestamp.

```
$timestamp = time();
$timestamp = $timestamp + 60*180; //180 minutes later
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix timestamp is expresses in seconds. So to add 180 mins to it, just convert to secs and add to the current timestamp like

```
$ts = strtotime('10/24/14 10:10');
$ts += 180*60;
echo date("m/d/Y H:i",$ts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on

```
$time = strtotime('10/24/14 10:10');
$afterAddMinutesTime = strtotime('+180 minutes', $time);

echo $afterAddMinutesTime; // this is new timestamp after add 180 minutes
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $afterAddMinutesTime); // just for checking
```